# Tcl: how to split string by blank lines

Tags: regex, tcl

could you please help me split a string into a list using as a delimiter a blank line ?
split using "\n\n" doesn't seem to work.
an example of such a string is the following :

```
Group: 1.1.1.1, (?)
   Source: 2.2.2.2 (?)
     Rate: 5382 pps/58470 kbps(1sec), 58469 kbps(last 30 secs), 58327 kbps(life avg)

Group: 3.3.3.3, (?)
   Source: 4.4.4.4 (?)
     Rate: 9150 pps/99399 kbps(1sec), 99398 kbps(last 30 secs), 85769 kbps(life avg)

Group: 5.5.5.5, (?)
   Source: 6.6.6.6 (?)
     Rate: 474 pps/5163 kbps(1sec), 5164 kbps(last 30 secs), 5144 kbps(life avg)
```

Comment: Would blank mean nothing in it as in, `^$`, (start-end)

Comment: thanks Rishi, but set group_source [ regexp -inline -all {^$} $itext ] ; doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2):

You may use the regular expression `^\s*$` to match all lines that only contain zero to N white space. Normally ^ and $ match start and end of line, unless MULTILINE mode is active.

Comment: thanks owlstead, but i need  to have a list, where each element is the string between "Group:" and including the line with "Rate:"

Comment: So what happens when you insert this regexp in your `split` method?

Comment: proc    get_mroute_active { itext }     {
        
        set group_source [ split $itext [ regexp -inline -all {^\s*$} $itext ] ] ;
        foreach record $group_source    {
                puts "--->" ;
                puts $record ;
        }
}

Comment: returns :--->


--->
 
--->
{
--->
G
--->
r
--->
o
--->
u
--->
p
--->
:
--->
 
--->
1
--->
1
--->
1
--->

Comment: set group_source [ split $itext [ regexp {^$} $itext ] ] ;
        foreach record $group_source    {
                puts "--->" ;
                puts $record ;
        }

Comment: returns : Group: 1.1.1.1, (?)
   Source: 2.2.2.2 (?)
     Rate: 732
--->
 pps/79519 kbps(1sec), 79519 kbps(last 1
--->
 secs), 79333 kbps(life avg)

Answer (score 1):

```
set mystring {Group: 1.1.1.1, (?)
    Source: 2.2.2.2 (?)
      Rate: 5382 pps/58470 kbps(1sec), 58469 kbps(last 30 secs), 58327 kbps(life avg)

Group: 3.3.3.3, (?)
    Source: 4.4.4.4 (?)
      Rate: 9150 pps/99399 kbps(1sec), 99398 kbps(last 30 secs), 85769 kbps(life avg)

Group: 5.5.5.5, (?)
    Source: 6.6.6.6 (?)
      Rate: 474 pps/5163 kbps(1sec), 5164 kbps(last 30 secs), 5144 kbps(life avg)}

set mylist {}
while {[regexp "(.*)\n\n(.*)" $mystring match part1 part2]} {
    lappend mylist $part2
    set mystring $part1
}
lappend mylist $part1
```

`mylist` now holds each 3 groups of non-blank lines *in reverse order*. There probably is some un-greedy regexp that will get it in order but I can't figure it out right now. One may always invert the list later, or replace the `lappend` lines by `set`, should the order be important.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `textutil` package from [Tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/), you can do this:

```
package require textutil
set paragraphs [textutil::splitx $data {(?n)^\s*\n}]
```

The `textutil::splitx` splits a string up by a regular expression, and here we supply a regular expression which matches a sequence of one-or-more visually-blank lines. (The `(?n)` means that `^` matches line-start instead of its usual string-start meaning; that's exactly what we want here.)

Comment: thanks Donal, but the script will run on a Cisco router, unfortunately i don't have the luxury of using textutil :(

Comment: @user690182, what version of Tcl? `info patchlevel`